# SSLHandshake error or Refused to connect error with Thingsboard API calls

Tags: azure, performance, cassandra, thingsboard, azure-load-testing

I have been **load testing** an instance of Thingsboard using **Jmeter** running on one of our **Azure VM**, I could test the below Scenario without any issue:
5K Threads, each with one HTTP Request (API telemetry) and one data point to one device

But when I started a test for 10K Threads with same HTTP request and data point ,I could see multiple requests throwing error such as

- SSL Handshake Exception: Remote host terminated the handshake
- Broken Pipe (write failed)
- Error 500
  etc

[Here's a log sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVmac.png)

After reducing threads per second to 500, I had no issues, so i increased it to 650 and saw a few Requests having errors

I found out about the API Rate limits although there were none set I had this issue, I set the API Rate limit with ample of head room but had no luck , reducing the rate limit to a very small range did affect the error percentage.

Server configurations are:
Hardware:
Azure D2as (2 vCPUs, 8GB RAM)

Software:
Thingsboard docker instance,
Single Cassandra DB (no load-balancer used),
Kafka Messaging Queue with zookeeper

API call: URL/api/v1/ACCESS_TOKEN/telemetry
(also tried with URL/api/plugins/plugins/ENTITY_TYPE/ENTITY_ID/timeseries/ANY?Scope=ANY )

Payload = {
"var_1": "NUMBER_BETWEEN_1_AND_1000"
}

After trying a few solution I did not see any improvements

Any help on resolving this issue is very much appreciated

Thanks!

PS: I am new to servers and load testing.

Initially, I tried restarting the docker container and server, Had no luck

I tried a local VM instance of same docker image , found no errors

I also tried a different Azure VM already hosted , Had the same issue

Added Rate limits higher than the test cases , did not resolve the issue